# Remote-SSH Vscode - problem - "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal, connection, remote-access

Situation:
I'm unable to connect to remote machnie via vscode + remote-SSH.
I CAN though connect to that machine using SSH from any shell.
Before the problem when I shut down my machine there was mandatory Windows update...

First error I get in terminal just after "You are connected to: [company-servername]" is:
[image]

After this there is never-ending error log whit most errors are similar to:
[image]

What I have already tried:

1. reinstalling Remote-ssh
2. killing vscode remote-server
3. making additional space on remote
4. running without any extensions except remote-ssh
5. reinstalling vscode
6. deleting all vscode config files and reinstalling
7. deleting vscode config files on remote in my home

I'm a bit stuck here, and our foreign 'Support' isn't very supportive...
maybe anyone had similar problem or has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

FYI I managed to fix the problem which was really trivial...

Some facts:

- Problem was with REMOTE SERVER not VSCODE
- As "tput: no value for $TERM" suggested something 'with terminal'

So what I did was clean my .bashrc to some generic sample. And it worked.

After investigation I figured that in my .bashrc I have
source /somepath/myAliases
which causes the problem. So what in that file was wrong?

In 'myAliases' there was broken alias where I used invalid quotation:

```
alias name='some commands' #OK
alias name="some commands" #OK
alias name=`some commands` # <-- this caused error shown above.
```

I hope this explanation may be of some use to any of you.

BR